# Keyword query language query validation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to validate Keyword Query Language query using either a library or MS Graph API?

Compliance center have Keyword Query Language builder but it seems it is not exposed as an endpoint.

Comment: Could you please explain your issue in details , and also tell us what you are trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @vickykumar - We are trying to validate the KQL query which user entered. We want to show an error when the query is not valid. Validation in the sense of syntax errors.

Comment: You can use Error handling and provide the code and the message in JSON object , for more info, see the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#error-handling